# Hangfire dashboard change refresh period

Tags: ajax, signalr, hangfire

`Hangfire dashboard` send ajax requests to the server to refresh data:
[image: Hangfire dashbord requestes]

It sends stats request as you can see on image. Every time it make request to database. It is possible to change number of requests in configuration or in other way? Because now is to often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change polling interval in dashboard options, the setting is in milliseconds. Refer [this](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/dashboard-excessive-database-access/4489)

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
 {
 StatsPollingInterval = 60000
 });
```